# Access 2010 display a google static map image

Tags: ms-access

I want to add a fixed Google static map image to my reports/forms in Microsoft access but am not sure how to alter the image control/objects to open a weblink to a .png file.

For example: I want to have the form display this image generated from below.

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.400470,-122.072981&zoom=17&maptype=satellite&size=500x300&sensor=false

Comment: Would you consider embedding the map in a web control instead of trying to capture the image and store it?

Comment: According to Google "Note that static maps may only be displayed within browser content; use of static maps outside of the browser is not allowed."  Perhaps a web browser control may satisfy that requirement.  However, my best guess is capturing and storing the map image to display in your form by another method would not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access 2010 has as new "native" web browser control. (pervious versions did not). This control can be bound to a column in the database. So, build a form, and paste in your URL to that field. This web control will display and update for you without any code. I susppose in theroy, this means you displaying the URL in a web browser and should be ok